# How do I adjust the FOV for Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The default FOV is rather low and annoying, I would like to increase the viewing angle up to something like 100, how do I do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your My Documents -> My Games -> Skyrim -> skyrim

Create a backup of the skyrim.ini file in case you need to change back later.

Open the file, then scroll down to where it says [General] (for me it was at the top of the file).

At the bottom of this section, add fdefaultfov=XX (where XX is the FOV value you want to change to), in your case it sounds like you want it to be 100.

Save, exit, and play!

Comment: Any idea how to do this on XBox?

Comment: It is my understanding that the "console" is not available on consoles, and certainly there are no configuration file tweaks.  Since they assume you will be playing in front of a TV, the FOV is probably hard set and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2):

At the console (<kbd>~</kbd> by default) Type "fov 100". There are reports that sprinting will reset this, so you may want to edit the Skyrim.ini file to set FOV.
Open the Skyrim.ini, scroll down to where it says [General], then 
at the bottom of this section, add fdefaultfov=100

Comment: In my experience, regardless of whether you used the `fov` command, sprinting changes the field of view, but only temporarily. Sometimes skyrim does randomly reset the field of view between play sessions though, so the ini file is a good suggestion. By the way, running `fov` in the console without any arguments seems to reset the field of view to default.